# Tamanho fixo + responsivo bootstrap 3

Tags: bootstrap

Estou desenvolvendo um site de um jornal, e tenho um problema para resolver.

O dono do Jornal não quer limitar tamanho das notícias. Com isso, não consigo deixar tudo encaixado, como uma notícia acaba sendo maior ou menor que a outra, sobram espaços em branco.

Havia dado a sugestão de limitar, mas eles recusaram, pois recebem notícias de outras agências e não podem ficar mudando o título/subtítulo.

Para explicar melhor, segue imagem de uma parte do site:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estes quadrados pretos eu fiz (porcamente) para tentar dar uma ideia do que estou precisando.

O site do Terra (terra.com.br) tem algo parecido com o que quero.

Alguma luz?

Comment: Ola, Não compreendi muito bem. O que pretende é fazer os "espaços"?

Comment: Preciso que as notícias se encaixem. Vou printar um exemplo.

Comment: Por favor, dê uma olhada: http://imgur.com/bP60tnv

Comment: Se olhar o site do Terra, as notícias podem ter vários tamanhos, mas os "quadrados" tem tamanho "fixo"...

Comment: Para o que analiso do site é que existe definido tamanho certo para 1 texto. Onde cada noticia vai usar se for maior pode usar 2 espaços ou quantos necessário para direito ou para baixo.

Comment: Eu queria usar o tamanho fixo para texto, exatamente para não ter essa diferença de tamanho... alguma ideia, @Tiago?

Comment: Se eu não conseguir resolver, como "matar" esse espaço em branco? Só um detalhe, as notícias vêm do Banco...

Comment: No seu caso é mais complicado porque tem a noticia completa, será muito dificil não existir espaços em branco (com a ordem que está).

Comment: Neste momento só vejo 2 passos possiveis.: 1 passar as noticias com ordem horizontal em vez de vertical. 2 fazer exatamente como fez na sua imagem adicionar "espaços" mas em vez dos "espaços" colocar imagem ou publicidade.

Comment: Entendo. A primeira opção parece interessante. Adicionar "espaços" não vai ser legal, pois as notícias tem tamanhos diferentes. Cada dia que eles mudam, ela pode ter título/subtítulo, ou não, por exemplo. O tamanho nunca é igual. Posso estar falando uma besteira, mas e se eu fixar o tamanho para o col-md e deixar o restante responsivo? Compreende o que eu digo?

Comment: O que vejo no print já tem 4 definidos com tamanhos fixos. Existe alguma regra para cada coluna ou são inseridos da esquerda para a direita?

Comment: Da esquerda pra direita. Os tamanhos não são fixos. Eles são de acordo com a quantidade de texto vindo do banco.

Comment: Uma coisa interessante no site do Terra é que alguns conteúdos tem pouco texto, mas as "caixas" tem tamanho fixo, o que deixa o site organizado. http://imgur.com/8pSMaP3